# Why is this get request giving an _isScalar exception?

Tags: angular

This code is giving me a weird exception:

```
  calculateLeave(username:string, password:string): Observable<number> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("username", username);
    params.append("password", password);
    return this.http.get("api/calculateleave", {params: params}).subscribe(res => res.json() as number);//this.http.get(this.apiPostUrl, {params: params}).toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Account)
  }
```

The exception goes: `Type Subscription is not assignable to type Observable<number>. Property _isScalar is missing in type 'subscription'.` Does anyone know what causes this error? I' m rather new to Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to return an Observable, then do not subscribe it there. Use `map()` instead of `subscribe()`.

`map()` will return an `Observable`.

`subscribe()` will return you the `Subscription`.

```
calculateLeave(username:string, password:string): Observable<number> {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append("username", username);
        params.append("password", password);
        return this.http.get("api/calculateleave", {params: params}).map(res => res.json() as number);
      }
```

You can then subscribe from the caller component in the following way

`calculateLeave('user', 'user').subscribe(data => console.log(data));`

**EDIT** : 
 Basically the error is all about the type mismatch. `Observable<number>` is not of type `Subscription`.

`_isScalar` is a property within `Observable` class which is not present within `Subscription` class. This is one way for a compiler to determine if the two Object types (expected return Object and actual return Object) match each other.

Comment: so how do I return an observable? If I remove the subscribe part it complains about not being able to return a response object because the return type is Observable

Comment: @Maurice I have added some description. Please check.